# How to recreate Execution Timeout Expired in EF6?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, savechanges

I want to recreate one error scenario from application hosted on Azure.

While updating entities ( while importing some files from excel ) there is an error throwed :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

error occurs when SaveChanges() is called

I think that inserting data is too large and that caused an issue. Due to that I need to recreate it locally. For that, I want to decrease this timeout but I can't do it. What I already tried to do:

First approach:

```
public AppDbContext() : base("AppDb")
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            Database.CommandTimeout = 10; // normlany this is set to 180 but I want to avoid 
                                             large time for waiting for error so I set it to 
                                             10
        }
```

Second approach:

I changed my connection string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Application-DEV;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connection Timeout=1
```

I also tried to make it this way:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                context.Database.CommandTimeout = 2;
                var breakPointOne = 1;

                context.FunctionalLocations.AddRange(data);
                context.SaveChanges();

                var breakPointTwo = 2;  // this breakpoint is reached after 50 seconds... 
            }
    // why exception isn't throwed?
```

anyone can tell me how to decrease this time? maybe I need to do something in db?

Comment: Can't you just add `Thread.Sleep(5000)` for a timeout of 5 seconds? Or override your `AppDbContext` and override savechanges and add a sleep before calling `base.Savechanges()`

Comment: no, because I need to have a long sql operation, not long operation in API

Comment: Can't you write a sql query with the `WAITFOR` command and send that using EF? like `context.FunctionalLocations.FromSqlRaw("WAITFOR DELAY '00:02'").ToList()`

Comment: okey, but I have scenario when I need to set it from ef6

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the scenario correctly but have you tried setting the `CommandTimeout()` options in the `OnConfiguring` method of DBContext. Something like this(code for EF Core)

```
    protected async override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var dbConn = configuration["DB:Connection"];

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(dbConn,
              x => x.CommandTimeout(10).EnableRetryOnFailure());
        }
```

Comment: thanks , it will be also useable, but You know how to configure it in ef6? I mean not core

Comment: yes, that's what I doing in my above examples, but this approach does not work